# why is Ngrx 8.2 effect throws type mismatch error

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular7, ngrx-effects

I made a small app that takes data(products list) from local json file and shows the names of the products on screen.
I have a service to get the data from the json:

```
export class ProductsService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

getProducts(): Observable<ProductInterface[]> {
return this.http.get<ProductInterface[]>('assets/data/products.json');
}
```

### the effect:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductsEffect {

loadProducts$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(loadProducts),
  switchMap(() => this.productService.getProducts()),
  map((products: ProductInterface[]) => loadProductsSuccess({products})),
  catchError(error => of(loadProductsFailed({error})))
));

constructor(private actions$: Actions, private productService: 
ProductsService) {
}
```

### the actions:

```
export enum productActionNames {
loadProducts = 'LOAD_PRODUCTS',
loadProductsSuccess = 'LOAD_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS',
loadProductsFailed = 'LOAD_PRODUCTS_FAILED',
changeProductPrice = 'CHANGE_PRODUCT_PRICE',
addProduct = 'ADD_PRODUCT',
removeProduct = 'REMOVE_PRODUCT'
}

export const loadProducts = createAction(productActionNames.loadProducts);
export const loadProductsSuccess =         
createAction(productActionNames.loadProductsSuccess, props<{ products: 
ProductInterface[] }>());
export const loadProductsFailed =         
createAction(productActionNames.loadProductsFailed, props<{ error: Error 
}>());
export const changeProductPrice =     
createAction(productActionNames.changeProductPrice, props<{ productName: 
string, newPrice: number }>());
export const addProduct = createAction(productActionNames.addProduct, 
props<{ newProduct: ProductInterface }>());
export const removeProduct = 
createAction(productActionNames.removeProduct, props<{ productName: string 
}>());
```

even-though everything is working fine I get this error that says:

```
Argument type ()=> Observable({products:ProductInterface[]} & TypedAction) | 
({error:Error} & TypedAction)> is not assignable to parameter type ()=> 
(((...args:any[])=> T extends false? Observable:Observable) | T extends 
false ? Observable:Observable)
```

how can I fix it?

here is a link to my project in github:
https://github.com/1Like1Prayer/temp

Comment: I'd say you're not returning a new action inside your `map` in your Effect.

Comment: But I'm returning loadProductsSuccess({products}) which is an action(you can find it in my actions file). Is there a different way I should do it?

Comment: Can you create reproduce code https://stackblitz.com ?

Comment: Sure! :) I'll edit the post when I'll have access to my computer. Might take a few hours..

Comment: Hi, you should return an instance of an action class. Try just changing it to `new loadProductsSuccess({products})`.

Comment: tried it, still got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You should return new action like this

Because effect expected us to return action Observable stream

```
loadProducts$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(loadProducts),
  switchMap(() => this.productService.getProducts()),
  map((products: ProductInterface[]) => new loadProductsSuccess({products})),
  catchError(error => of(loadProductsFailed({error})))
));
```